# Trying to launch media creation tool - "Something happened 0x80070002 - 0x20016"

Tags: windows-10

I'm getting the "Something happened 0x80070002 - 0x20016" error message when trying to launch the Media Creation Tool. I wonder what this could mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/949234/windows-10-upgrade-error-0x80070002 this question (answer) covers a method for fixing one sort of error of that type. to download the microsoft update troubleshooter, and use it. The error general, is usualy a files, or access to, or permission, or storage type of issue. that can include datastore, software distribution local, and system file integrity (which a SFC scan would be used for)

Answer (score 3):

I was seeing the Something happened 0x80070002 - 0x20016" error (as per image below) when running the media creation tool as well. What worked for me was the following fix from [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/3fio5q/cant_install_windows_10_have_tried_wuauclt_have/). I was having to run the tool as I hadn't recieved a notification to reserve a copy and it wasn't showing up in Windows Update until the below change in the registry.

1. Click on Start, search for regedit.
2. With regedit open, proceed to the following path. Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\OSUpgrade
3. Right click on the right side window and go to New -> DWORD (32-bit) value
4. Rename the new value to "AllowOSUpgrade" without the " quotations and make sure it is exactly the same as it is case sensitive.
5. Double click on the newly created value AllowOSUpgrade and change the value to 1 with hexidecimal base.
6. Close regedit and run Windows Update again. Windows 10 should pop up and you can then download it.

[image]

Comment: I did reserve upgrade, and this fix didn't solve my problem.

Comment: And what problem exactly are you faced with?

Comment: See the question above.

Comment: It is worth noting that you can't upgrade Enterprise.

Comment: I couldn't find `OSUpgrade`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Windows 10 Upgrade Problems: Something Happened Error

Automated fix: Run the [Windows Update Troubleshooter](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9830262).

Manual fix: See below.

---

#### Automated fix

> Even when users get Windows 10 running on their PCs, they are running into issues. Once issue that happens is simply being referred to as the Something Happened error. It’s called that because that’s what shows up on-screen.
>
> Microsoft has a tool to automatically fix this issue and it is called the [Windows Update Troubleshooter](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9830262). If you’re an experienced user you can manually try and fix this with the Command Prompt by [following these instructions](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/unable-to-upgrade-to-windows-10-something-happened/be12b76d-af02-46a1-a00c-4e4af0c29588).

Source [7 Windows 10 Upgrade Problems & How to Fix Them](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2015/07/30/7-windows-10-upgrade-problems-how-to-fix-them/)

---

#### Manual fix

> This issue might also occur due to corruption in Windows Update
>   component files. I suggest you to reset Windows Update component.
>   Kindly follow the below given steps.
>
> 1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, select Command prompt (Admin) to bring up elevated Command prompt.
> 2. Stop the BITS service, the Windows Update service, and the Cryptographic service. To do this, at a command prompt, type the
>      following commands. Make sure that you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after
>      you type each command.
>
>    - `net stop bits`
>    - `net stop wuauserv`
>    - `net stop appidsvc`
>    - `net stop cryptsvc`
> 3. Rename the software distribution folders backup copies. To do this, at a command prompt, type the following commands. Make sure that
>      you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after you type each command.
>
>    - `Ren %systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.bak`
>    - `Ren %systemroot%\system32\catroot2 catroot2.bak`
> 4. Restart the BITS service, the Windows Update service, and the Cryptographic service. To do this, at a command prompt, type the
>      following commands. Make sure that you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after
>      you type each command.
>
>    - `net start bits`
>    - `net start wuauserv`
>    - `net start appidsvc`
>    - `net start cryptsvc`
> 5. Restart your PC and check if it works this time when you try to update.

Source [Unable to Upgrade to Windows 10 - Something Happened error](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/unable-to-upgrade-to-windows-10-something-happened/be12b76d-af02-46a1-a00c-4e4af0c29588)

Answer (score 1):

Besides any other fixes presented in these answers, the cache folders for the files needed to create the media should also be erased. Corruption of these files is also a cause of failure to create the media.

Erase the two cache folders present at C:\, named:

$WINDOWS.~BT
$Windows.~WS

You might need to modify the View parameters of C: as to be possible to view hidden and system folders and files.

After this, the Media Creation Tool will download the needed files again.

Comment: This answer worked for me and it is much easier than the above answers!